how to extract numeric values on both sides of colon
I am writing a PHP script to extract numeric values on both sides of : in the following string Bonus 1:1. The script should work even if the string is Bonus 1:1 xyz. Can someone help me?

We might need more than just two sample strings?  Do these samples represent the minimum and maximum complexity/variability of these strings? Are these numbers always integers or might they be floats?  Ever negative numbers? Is the first word always statically "Bonus"?
